# marmap package, getNOAA.bathy

Tags: r

I have a vector of latitude and longitude values, from trawl data in the NE Atlantic. Unfortunately there was no depth information with these positions. I was thinking I could generate the depth information with getNOAA.bathy (package MARMAP in R). This package also has a function called get.depth() which allows the user to click a map and generate the depth at that position.

So my question is, can I generate a vector of depths, from my vectors of lat and lon automatically, without clicking the map for each (I've 700 entries to do)?

```
##load package
library(marmap)

## generate bathymetric data
bio_depth<-getNOAA.bathy(-25, -5, 50, 68)
## vectors of lat, lon (reduced sample for demo purposes)
lat<-c(54.487, 54.487, 54.487, 54.535, 54.535)
lon<-c(-5.187, -5.187, -5.187, -5.267, -5.267)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this might be easier than you think. The `bio_depth` matrix you created is actually just a big matrix with all the depths, with the latitude and longitude as row names and column names. So you could directly extract the depths like this:

```
library(marmap)

## generate bathymetric data
bio_depth<-getNOAA.bathy(-25, -5, 50, 68)
## vectors of lat, lon (reduced sample for demo purposes)
lat<-c(54.487, 54.487, 54.487, 54.535, 54.535)
lon<-c(-5.187, -5.187, -5.187, -5.267, -5.267)

# Grab the lat/long from the row names
mat.lon <- as.numeric(rownames(bio_depth))
mat.lat <- as.numeric(colnames(bio_depth))

# For each lat/long, exact matches are unlikely, find the range 
# in which each one falls.
x<-findInterval(lon,mat.lon)
y<-findInterval(lat,mat.lat)
# Find depth of each lat/long
bio_depth[cbind(x,y)]
# [1] -108 -108 -108 -108 -108
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your input. I was just working on another solution along the same lines, but not as graceful. I will post it up shortly.

Comment: Using all.inside=T, in the findInterval function was necessary to compute depth for all my lat/lon.

Comment: Great. If you're happy with the answer, you can click the checkbox to the side of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to use the new `get.depth` function from `marmap 0.8` and above to do this. All you have to do is:

```
library(marmap)

## generate bathymetric data
bio_depth<-getNOAA.bathy(-25, -5, 50, 68)

## vectors of lat, lon (reduced sample for demo purposes)
lat<-c(54.487, 54.487, 54.487, 54.535, 54.535)
lon<-c(-5.187, -5.187, -5.187, -5.267, -5.267)

get.depth(bio_depth, x=lon, y=lat, locator=F)

#      Lon    Lat Depth
# 1 -5.187 54.487  -108
# 2 -5.187 54.487  -108
# 3 -5.187 54.487  -108
# 4 -5.267 54.535  -126
# 5 -5.267 54.535  -126
```

Comment: Hi Benoit, that is great. Another excellent function for your package.